# Still need a cookie with Server-side Session for Auth?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We are rolling our own auth provider and gonna do your typical hold auth session data in HttpContext.Current.Session.  My question is, then do we still need to persist stuff client-side like their UserID or sessionID?

I'm trying to think about when the HttpContext dies, like if we recycle the app pool or the server runs out of memory or we explicitly clear the HttpContext for a user to force a closed session.

Do I need to make sure that they have already a cookie that we also send a delete request to?

I'm trying to understand why we need a cookie to persist the session.  My guess is they could hop on another machine, log in with the same username and password and now we have 2 sessions going on in the server!  not good right?  So you'd need a cookie to check that sessionID each and every time they request to our server right?  If it doesn't match, delete their session server-side, send a delete cookie request, and redirect them back to login.  Or if they forcefully delete their browser cookie for the current session ID I'd see that thus close out their HttpContext session and redirect them to login again right?

I'm rolling my own stuff, not using Forms Auth ticket.

Anyone have comments on why I'd need a cookie when we're holding session data in memory?   And we don't want to use cookieless where we're screwing up our url and it's not safe to send that stuff over url even though it's encrypted.

The guys at work here say they don't want to delete cookies if we use them, that the expiration date should be like in 60-90 days.

We're using MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you are looking to achieve here:

If the user closes his browser his session is typically gone. If he re-opens his browser he has to re-login. also the session will expire automatically at some point. The user will need to re-login at that point.

This is ok sometimes. I mean sometimes you want that right?

If the app you are building is not some super-secure service then you can use a cookie to store SOME user details inside. I store the user's id and encrypt it before sending it along with the response. Every time I get that cookie in the request I decrypt the contents and login the user automatically.

This means that the user is always logged in unless he clears his cookies or explicitly log out.

Consider this though: you can store every little user detail in that cookie. just store his id or something. but if you store his id then you will need to load the User object every time you get that cookie. This is EVERY request so its not great fro your db. In this case, you can use the Session as a buffer. If you encounter this cookie load the user in the session. in future request check the session first and then the cookie. This way you essentially "cache" the user details in the session and on log out you have to clear the cookie as well as the session.

Hope this helps.